# Evaluating an expression on one line

Tags: syntax

Is it possible to evaluate an expresson on one line?

I have a linear algebra problem to re-write the straight line $-x=1-3y=-1-2z$ to a 'vector form';

```
line = {x, y, z} /. Solve[{{-x, 1 - 3 y, -1 - 2 z} == {1, 1, 1} t}, {x, y, z}][[1]];
```

and I want to extract the 'fix/start point' and the directional vector of `line` (in lack of better knowledge of any inbuilt functions in M.) by

```
t = 0;
p0 = line;
t = 1;
n = line - p0;
```

These 4 lines I think could be merged to two lines, but I don't know  the syntax for it, something in the line of

```
p0 = line @{t=0};
n = line-p0 @{t=1};
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: mf67, may I suggest that you revisit [your questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/55498/mf67?tab=questions) and consider accepting any answers that best solve your problem.

Comment: There is a blue popup 'flash' each time but I don't manage to read it before it disappears. Are there instructions somewhere to read to correctly process answers?

Comment: mf67,  this may be useful: [Accepting an aswer: how does it work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) with a list of lists of rules (`{a->b}`):

```
line /. {{t -> 0}, {t -> 1}}
```

> {{0, 1/3, -(1/2)}, {-1, 0, -1}}

To get `p0` and `n` in a single line:

```
{p0, n} = {#, #2 - #} & @@ (line /. {{t -> 0}, {t -> 1}})
```

> {{0, 1/3, -(1/2)}, {-1, -(1/3), -(1/2)}}

Note: The same trick in a simpler example:

```
x /. {{x -> 100}, {x -> 5}, {x -> abc}}
```

> {100, 5, abc}